# Android target: not installed Cordova Requirements

Tags: macos, android-studio, cordova, sdk, zsh

I've tried reading on Stack Overflow as well as additional google pages. I think I might have the Path wrong slightly but I'm not sure why its not wronging as it does look correct.

Can someone please assist and let me know if this is correct. I also do have Android Studio installed but I am trying to do this via the Cordova CLI.

I am also quite new to using Zsh, so I have edited both profiles that one and the bash profile but still no effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't understand what's wrong.

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/lyntree/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Users/lyntree/Library/Android/sdk

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home

export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk/tools

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/lyntree/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/lyntree/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/lyntree/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/90iBj.jpg
```

Comment: Can anyone assist, please?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The wrong version of JAVA was installed SE11 - Should be JAVA Version SE8.

As soon as I did this:

Cordova Requirements (WORKED!)
Cordova Build Android (Started to work and failed in build - due to another java issue with tools now)...

I hope this helps anyone!